# Vim filetype detection does not trigger syntax highlighting

Tags: vim

I'm trying to detect Go files in vim. I've set this up normally on other computers but this one is stuck.

```
:set filetype?
filetype=go
```

So it knows that it's a go file, but isn't triggering the syntax highlighting.

However,

```
:set filetype=go
```

triggers it correctly.

```
:filetype detect
```

doesn't work, and reopening the file
    :e!
turns syntax highlighting off, even though filetype remains set to "go".

I have

```
set rtp+=/usr/local/go/misc/vim
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

in my .vimrc (as the instructions say).

What's going on? I suspect there's some other configuration that's undoing the syntax highlighting, but lack the knowledge of where to find it.

Comment: If you could share your vimrc file we might be able to help more

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is… However, you can try `:scriptnames` to see what files were loaded by Vim.

One step further, you can `set verbose=9` in your `.vimrc` and restart Vim. Careful, this is *really* verbose, try to tweak that number down.